# Упаковка скрипта python, который создаёт службу Windows

Tags: python, windows, служба

Имеется python скрипт, который создаёт службу Windows

```js
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
from server import *
 
class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Service"
    _svc_description_ = "Service Description"
 
    def __init__(self,args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self,args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None,0,0,None)
        self.hWaitResume = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        self.timeout = 10000 
        self.resumeTimeout = 1000
        self._paused = False
 
    def SvcStop(self):
        stop_server()
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STOPPED,
                              (self._svc_name_, ''))

       
    def SvcPause(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING)
        self._paused = True
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_PAUSED)
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("The %s service has paused." % (self._svc_name_, ))
   
    def SvcContinue(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitResume)
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_RUNNING)
        servicemanager.LogInfoMsg("The %s service has resumed." % (self._svc_name_, ))
               
 
    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()  
  
    def main(self):
        while True:
            run_server()

if __name__ == '__main__':
   win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Служба успешно устанавливается через cmd командой: python service.py install
Также успешно запускается вызовом: net start Service и останавливается: net stop Service

Вопрос заключается в следующем: можно ли каким-то образом упаковать этот скрипт и все связанные с ним скрипты в exe или в какой-нибудь установочный файл под Windows, чтобы при запуске автоматически устанавливалась и запускалась эта служба? Желательно, чтобы она еще автоматически запускалась при старте системы. Такое вообще возможно?

Пробовал упаковывать с помощью pyinstaller в exe, все упаковывается, но служба не устанавливается даже через cmd с ошибкой "1053 служба не ответила на запрос своевременно".